# How to compute the bazel workspace name in a macro?

Tags: bazel

I want to compute the workspace name during the execution of a bazel macro. If this was in a rule I could use `ctx.workspace_name()`, but I don't have a `ctx` object in a macro. There are `native.package_name()` and `native.repository_name()` but no `native.workspace_name()`.

I need this as I want to compute the path within the docker image that my files are put by the docker rules, so that I can construct the correct `entrypoint` argument.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/lang/image.bzl#L84

Answer (score 0):

`native.repository_name()` is exactly what you are looking for. It's confusing that there is `workspace_name()` from `ctx` and `repository_name()` from `native` ([#4092](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4092)).